# Recaptcha v3 issue

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, grecaptcha

Suddenly Recaptcha V3 stopped working. I am getting error.
**Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service. Please check your internet connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.**.

But internet is fine. On investigation found that https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Lfe5HcUAAAAAGrF4-sXx5YFaoCETFY1qZ6V8pGM&co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuaW50ZXJyYWlsLmV1OjQ0Mw..&hl=en-GB&v=NjbyeWjjFy97MXGZ40KrXu3v&size=invisible&cb=z9bncod50jz9
is throwing 404 error. This gets added by recaptcha js on the page. The strange thing is **api2** is twice in the url, if I remove one it returns 200 and loads the recaptcha logo. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Lfe5HcUAAAAAGrF4-sXx5YFaoCETFY1qZ6V8pGM&co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuaW50ZXJyYWlsLmV1OjQ0Mw..&hl=en-GB&v=NjbyeWjjFy97MXGZ40KrXu3v&size=invisible&cb=z9bncod50jz9

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that no 3rd party library or your own JavaScript files are fiddling with `String.prototype`. Some `String` methods have been added to the ECMAScript 2015 specification and old scripts are still containing these. Just search for occurrences of `String.prototype`. At least that fixed it for me.